# THREE.SkinnedMesh boneTexture leaks

Tags: three.js

It appears that the DataTexture boneTexture created in SkinnedMesh is never disposed automatically.

Are we supposed to dispose of it ourselves when the mesh is removed from the scene? I can't seem to find any documentation or examples that cover this.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you follow the pattern in [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_test_memory.html) example and add `mesh.boneTexture.dispose();`?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine, I was just surprised that it doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere. Perhaps the memory example should be amended with a skinned mesh.

Comment: OK. I've created an answer which you can "accept" by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the pattern in [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_test_memory.html) example and add

```
mesh.boneTexture.dispose();
```

three.js r.61

Comment: I'll accept this, but it doesn't 'really' answer the question. A boneTexture can be disposed just like any other Texture, with .dispose, but the question was "are we supposed to?"

I suppose that would be more suitable for a github issue.

Comment: As the library is written, yes, you are "supposed" to. If you feel it should be handled for you, you are free to file a suggestion on github.